# Solc Compiler : File import callback not supported

Tags: solidity, solc, compiler

As a context I am trying to fork uniswap v2 contracts using my own compiler and deploy files. I am not using truffle, as I want to deeply understand before using a framework.

When I run my compiler, I get this error :

```
  formattedMessage: 'Contract:3:1: ParserError: Source "interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol" not found: File import callback not supported\n' +
    "import './interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol';\r\n" +
    '^------------------------------------------^\n',
  message: 'Source "interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol" not found: File import callback not supported',
```

I tried to copy all contracts into the contract that I was trying to deploy, and it worked. But I can't do this for every contract ...

Here is my compiler file :
`

```
const path = require("path");
const solc = require("solc"); //don't forget to install the right solc version !
const fs = require("fs-extra");

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "build");

fs.removeSync(buildPath);

function compileContract(Contract) {
    const contractPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./", Contract);
    
    const contractSourceCode = fs.readFileSync(contractPath, "utf8");
    
    fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

    var input = {
        language: 'Solidity',
        sources: {
            Contract : {
                content: contractSourceCode
            }
        },
        settings: {
            optimizer: {
                enabled: true
            },
            outputSelection: {
                '*': {
                    '*': [ '*' ]
                }
            }
        }
    };

    const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
    console.log(output);

    for(let contractName in output.contracts.Contract) {
        fs.outputJsonSync(
            path.resolve(buildPath, `${contractName}.json`),
            output.contracts.Contract[contractName]
        );
    }
    
}

// compileContract("UniswapV2Pair.sol");
compileContract("UniswapV2Factory.sol");
compileContract("UniswapV2ERC20.sol");
```

I am using solc@0.5.16

And here are the files I am trying to deploy : https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/tree/master/contracts

Comment: Check the [import callback](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/path-resolution.html#import-callback) from the solidity docs. Also check the [usage info](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#example-usage-with-import-callback) on the solcjs. I hope it will help you understand what a monster are you dealing with.
Also, maybe someone will help if you provide more of your compiling script and what command do you run to execute it. Please, be sure provide this information.

Comment: Thank you mate, I'll read it now. About the compiling script this is all I have in the compile.js file. Basically it create a build folder and fill it with compiled contracts. And I use "node compile.js" to run it

Comment: Well, after reading those docs many times, and trying different solutions, I can't understand how to solve the problem ..  i tried to import files directly from the @uniswap/v2-core dependency, doesn't work.

Tried to put the file in the same folder, doesn't work.

Tried to import with relative or direct import, doesn't change anything.

Comment: As far as I understood from the manual in github for solcjs and your error description you should implement import callback yourself because it doesn't work in solcjs. Did you see the example in the section from github? The function findImports specifically implements import callback to resolve imports. I cannot try it on my own, unfortunately because my OS doesn't support 0.5.16 solcjs

Comment: Here https://github.com/alincode/solc-import. Maybe you will find this useful in your coding.

Comment: Ok, so, I tried to use it yesterday, but I think I misunderstand something. Thank you for your great help Prorok, it's deeply appreciated. 

So, this findImport function basically take an import path from the contract we want to compile. And in the findImport function, we check the path, and if it's the one we want to import, we hardcode the content of the imported contract in the return statement ?

I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: I tried to find an elegant solution for your problem but on every forum I visited it was said that there will be no import resolving for solc-js in the future. One of the users mentioned that it is actually a feature, because you can program whatever you want in the resolution function - for example, like in Remix IDE, you can import files from Github, Swarm or IPFS. So while the standard local import resolving becomes unavailable by default, the feature of an import callback solc-js is a possibility to create such custom functions where you can program whatever way of resolving path you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that I wrote to compile files with import statements with solc@0.5.16. The script compile the files and put them into a build folder as a json file.

Thanks for helping me making this !

```
"use-strict";

const path = require("path");
const solc = require("solc"); //don"t forget to install the right solc version !
const fs = require("fs-extra");

// interfaces folder
const IERC20SourceCode = fs.readFileSync("./interfaces/IERC20.sol");
const IUniswapV2CalleeSourceCode = fs.readFileSync("./interfaces/IUniswapV2Callee.sol");
const IUniswapV2ERC20SourceCode = fs.readFileSync("./interfaces/IUniswapV2ERC20.sol");
const IUniswapV2FactorySourceCode = fs.readFileSync("./interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol");
const IUniswapV2PairSourceCode = fs.readFileSync("./interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol");

// libraries folder
const MathSourceCode = fs.readFileSync("./libraries/Math.sol");
const UQ112x112SourceCode = fs.readFileSync("./libraries/UQ112x112.sol");
const SafeMathSourceCode = fs.readFileSync("./libraries/SafeMath.sol");

// core folder
const UniswapV2PairSourceCode = fs.readFileSync("./UniswapV2Pair.sol");
const UniswapV2ERC20SourceCode = fs.readFileSync("./UniswapV2ERC20.sol");
const UniswapV2FactorySourceCode = fs.readFileSync("./UniswapV2Factory.sol");

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "build");

fs.removeSync(buildPath);

function compileContract(Contract) {
    const contractPath = path.resolve(__dirname, ...Contract);  
    
    const contractSourceCode = fs.readFileSync(contractPath, "utf8");
    
    fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

    var input = {
        language: "Solidity",
        sources: {
            Contract: {
                content: contractSourceCode
            }
        },
        settings: {
            optimizer: {
                enabled: true
            },
            outputSelection: {
                "*": {
                    "*": [ "*" ]
                }
            }
        }
    };

    function findImports(path) {
        if (path === "interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol") return { contents: `${IUniswapV2FactorySourceCode}` };
        if (path === "interfaces/IERC20.sol") return { contents: `${IERC20SourceCode}` };
        if (path === "interfaces/IUniswapV2Callee.sol") return { contents: `${IUniswapV2CalleeSourceCode}` };
        if (path === "interfaces/IUniswapV2ERC20.sol") return { contents: `${IUniswapV2ERC20SourceCode}` };
        if (path === "interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol") return { contents: `${IUniswapV2PairSourceCode}` };
        if (path === "libraries/Math.sol") return { contents: `${MathSourceCode}` };
        if (path === "libraries/UQ112x112.sol") return { contents: `${UQ112x112SourceCode}` };
        if (path === "libraries/SafeMath.sol") return { contents: `${SafeMathSourceCode}` };
        if (path === "UniswapV2Pair.sol") return { contents: `${UniswapV2PairSourceCode}` };
        if (path === "UniswapV2ERC20.sol") return { contents: `${UniswapV2ERC20SourceCode}` };
        if (path === "UniswapV2Factory.sol") return { contents: `${UniswapV2FactorySourceCode}` };
        else return { error: "File not found" };
      }

    let output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input), { import: findImports }));

    for(let contractName in output.contracts.Contract) {
        fs.outputJsonSync(
            path.resolve(buildPath, `${contractName}.json`),
            output.contracts.Contract[contractName]
        );
    }    
}

compileContract(["./", "UniswapV2Factory.sol"]);
compileContract(["./", "UniswapV2Pair.sol"]);
compileContract(["./", "UniswapV2ERC20.sol"]);
compileContract(["./", "libraries", "Math.sol"]);
compileContract(["./", "libraries", "SafeMath.sol"]);
compileContract(["./", "libraries", "UQ112x112.sol"]);
compileContract(["./", "interfaces", "IUniswapV2Factory.sol"]);
compileContract(["./", "interfaces", "IERC20.sol"]);
compileContract(["./", "interfaces", "IUniswapV2Callee.sol"]);
compileContract(["./", "interfaces", "IUniswapV2ERC20.sol"]);
compileContract(["./", "interfaces", "IUniswapV2Pair.sol"]);
```

Comment: Actually what you can do is to remove questions from this answer, mark this as your self-answer and create a separate question post about whether you can improve the solution somehow with link to this question post. This would remove questions from the answer section which is always good and also it would draw more attention from the users because the question will be shown as with no answer.

Comment: all right, thanks Prorok for taking the time, I'll do this !

Answer (score 0):

You should use options like `--base-path` and `--include-path` to avoid it

here is an example

```
./node_modules/.bin/solcjs --include-path ./node_modules/ --base-path ./contracts/ --evm-version constantinople ./contracts/GnosisSafe.sol --bin --abi
```